# downloading android device definitions for ADT

Tags: android, adt

can I download **android device definitions** for ADT directly. Are they available. Can someone suggest me a useful resource for Samsung device definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For older devices, Samsung offer:
[Samsung Definitions Page](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095)

For anything new, they offer [Remote Test Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) which requires uploading your app using Java Web Start into a browser-based equivalent of AVD.

SDK Tools, guides and much more available on the site. Most things require doing it their way.

Nokia offer some images, as well as the Nokia SDK which is a locally installed equivalent of the Samsung tool. [Nokia Developer Downloads](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/downloads)

HTC have been the most welcoming for developers of all the major brands.
[HTC Dev](http://www.htcdev.com/)

Most of these links were found within 5 minutes.
Search for: `[brand] developer tools`

Another alternative is find the specs & skin for the device you wish to emulate, create device manually entering the equivalent values, apply skin, and Start.